# Laravel / Stripe: Server aborted the SSL

Tags: laravel, ssl, stripe-payments

I'm using laravel 5.4 and stripe, I try to go on my profile (local dev): http://127.0.0.1:8000/account but I get this error that I had not before:

> Unexpected error communicating with Stripe. If this problem persists, let us know at support@stripe.com.
>   (Network error [errno 35]: Server aborted the SSL handshake)

I don't know why or what can I do to fix this issue.

Thanks for your help

Comment: It might requires SSL installed on your local environment. Either install it or try to deploy codes on some development environment where SSL is installed.

Comment: As @Dev mentioned before you should create a self singed ssl certificate. 
This is a nice tutorial from digital ocean: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-create-a-self-signed-ssl-certificate-for-apache-in-ubuntu-16-04

Answer (score 1):

Stripe requires a connection with SSL. If you are not using SSL on your local environment or if you have an invalid certificate it will fail.

Answer (score 0):

As @lukas-r reply, you can find the solution by following this:

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-create-a-self-signed-ssl-certificate-for-apache-in-ubuntu-16-04